# What permission do you need to check-in other's article at any time?

Tags: acl

As a super user you can do that. I want to grant this privilege to another group of users, but I can't find where to set this. In global configuration there is a `check-in` but it doesn't work for me. As you can see in below picture I change "Access administration Interface" to "Allowed" but when manager users try to check-in other's article, they are still getting the "check-in user don't match the check-out user" error.
[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Component layouts and `com_checkin` itself uses  `core.manage` (Access Administrator Interface) check but component models use `core.admin` (Configure ACL & Options) checks. Until it's fixed you'd need to assign both permissions.

Comment: @shen You have accepted just **15** answers of your **69** active questions.  Please do more to support the community that supports you. If your questions are resolved, please upvote correct/helpful answers and accept the best resolving answer.  If your questions are not resolved, please take the time to improve them so that volunteers can better understand what is required.  Your questions are valuable to this community, but resolved questions are what we are truly striving for.  Furthermore, volunteers that earn little green `+10`s in their rep inbox are more likely to continue volunteering.

Comment: I raised an issue about this problem a while ago https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/22466